# ASP.NET Core MVC - Javascript library loads but its functions aren't recognized

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-5, asp.net5

I am creating an ASP.NET Core MVC application (.NET version 5) where I am trying to use a Javascript library called FullCalendar. I added the library's Javascript using a CDN link in a script tag at the bottom of the app's layout (see _Layout.cshtml) and linked the library's stylesheet (also using a CDN).

_Layout.cshtml:

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity
@using Infrastructure
@inject UserManager<ApplicationUser> UserMananager;

@{
    var user = await UserMananager.GetUserAsync(User);
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>@ViewData["Title"] - App</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link href='https://unpkg.com/boxicons@2.0.9/css/boxicons.min.css' rel='stylesheet'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar@@5.1.0/main.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div class="sidebar">
        ...
    </div>

    <div class="home_content">
        @RenderBody()
    </div>

    <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar@@5.1.0/main.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
    @await RenderSectionAsync("Scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

I use the library in one of my razor pages like this:

Index.cshtml:

```
@section Scripts {
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {    
            $("#calendar").fullCalendar({ // This function is not recognized
                header: {
                    left: "",
                    center: "prev title next",
                    right: ""
                },
                eventClick: function(event, jsEvent, view) {
                    $("#modalTitle").html(event.title);
                    $("#modalBody").html(event.description);
                    $("#eventUrl").attr("href", event.url);
                    $("#fullCalModal").modal();
                    return false;
                },
                events: "@Url.Action("GetAppointments", "Appointment")"
            })
        })
    </script>
}

<div class="container">
    <div id="calendar">
    </div>
    <div id="fullCalModal" class="modal fade">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">x</span><span class="sr-only">close</span></button>
                    <h3 id="modalTitle" class="modal-title"></h3>
                </div>
                <div id="modalBody" class="modal-body">

                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <a class="btn btn-primary" id="eventUrl" target="_blank">Event Page</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

However, when I open the page the following error pops up in the console:

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).fullCalendar is not a function

I looked at the network tab and the FullCalendar library seems to load just fine and the jQuery library to loads before the FullCalendar library (as it should):
[Network tab screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B5lpL.jpg)

Would anyone know what's going wrong here?

Comment: The cdn link is bad. Go to: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar@@5.1.0/main.min.js In a browser, and you get the following: `Couldn't find the requested release version @5.1.0.`

Comment: Try the cdn with only 1 `@` https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar@5.1.0/main.min.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar@@5.1.0/main.min.js"></script>
```

First, if directly access the above fullcalendar reference, it couldn't find this version package.

[image]

So, you could try to use the 5.10.1 version fullcalendar reference, like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar@5.10.1/main.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar@5.10.1/main.min.js"></script>
```

Second, if you check the [fullcalendar document](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/initialize-globals), you can see that, in Fullcalendar V5 version, we should create a `FullCalendar.Calendar` object to render the fullcalendar, instead of using the fullCalendar function. code like this:

```
<div id="calendar">
</div>
@section Scripts {  
    <script>

      document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
        var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
          initialView: 'dayGridMonth'
        });
        calendar.render();
      });

    </script>
}
```

The result as below:

[image]

For the fullCalendar function, this might apply to the previous version fullCalendar, like [this sample](https://codepen.io/dcangulo/pen/PgxXbb)(it using fullCalendar 3.10.0 version and the fullCalendar function, if you add the JS reference and copy the code to Asp.net core application, it also works well).

Comment: Oh, I mistakenly thought that the fullCalendar function also applied for the newer versions and thought ASP.NET might didn't like the @ symbol (and read that a double @ escapes the sign). Thank you very much!